# cytoscape simple startup not working

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want to use the cytoscape.js library for my project. But I cannot get it running. This is the example page I use.

http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/

I make a html document and include the library. But it does not visualize the example graph.

I cannot even get my code in this post :S.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to use the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) site to demonstrate your code.

Anyway, [here](https://ricardo-orange.codio.io/single.html) you can find another simple example of using cytoscape.js, where I made some effort to put it all in a single file for demonstrations porpouses.

Comment: Your "here" link which presumably contains the answer shows only `java.lang.NullPointerException`. BTW: link-only answers are not welcome practice. One of the reasons is that if the linked site goes down the answer becomes value-less and void. Discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers